# Does RabbitMQ offer the following features?

Tags: rabbitmq, nservicebus

I have used N Service Bus in one of my projects recently and although I like it but I am still looking for alternate options. I have stumbled on RabbitMQ but before I give it a try I want to find out the following things:

1-  Is it reliable? (With N Service Bus if a message gets published to the queue the listener always receives it).

2-  If the client is down does it automatically gets the message when it becomes available? like in NSB.

3-  Is it lightweight on resources (NSB is very lightweight)?

4-  Is it easy to integrate with .Net?

5-  Is the Admin panel available with Open Source free version?

6-  Is it easy to track down problems if messages are not getting published etc? (This is the pain with NSB)

7-  Does it support complex scenarios where there might be N number of Listeners for a message or a single listener that needs to listen to multiple messages etc?

8-  Is it configurable from code? (Personally I don’t like to use heave Config files, just personal choice )

9-  Is the .Net API of RabbitMQ clean or does it make the code messy?

Kindly give me your feedback. All the above questions are relevant to the Open Source version, I don’t want to buy licensed version yet.
Also suggest if there are any other options available out there.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you read the RabbitMQ website and documentation to try to answer these questions?

Comment: RabbitMQ is a message queuing technology similar to MSMQ. NServiceBus leverages a messaging queuing technology to reliably send messages between endpoints. NServiceBus uses MSMQ by default but can be configured to use RabbitMQ as well. The answer to 1-8 is "it depends". The answer to 9 is "you have to write a lot more code so there is more of a chance of having messy code".

Comment: I believe most of the questions I asked can be answered by experience of its usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it reliable? (With N Service Bus if a message gets published to the queue the listener always receives it).

Yes. In addition you have more control over the 'reliability' in rabbitmq, for example you can specify that a queue is durable (which means that messages are persisted to disk before being delivered).

2- If the client is down does it automatically gets the message when it becomes available? like in NSB.

Yes.

3- Is it lightweight on resources (NSB is very lightweight)?

RabbitMq is written in erlang and runs as it's own process. You have a lot of insight into how it is consuming memory, but the actual resource usage will be dependent on your workload.

4- Is it easy to integrate with .Net?

Yes. The basic rabbitmq C# wrapper is very easy to use and offers a very simple abstraction over the rabbitmq concepts. There are higher level libraries available if you're coming from NServiceBus (which I believe has a RabbitMQ adapter). You should look at MassTransit, which can use RabbitMQ as well as MSMQ as a transport, and libraries like my own [chinchilla](https://github.com/jonnii/chinchilla) or EasyNetQ which are RabbitMQ only.

5- Is the Admin panel available with Open Source free version?

Yes.

6- Is it easy to track down problems if messages are not getting published etc? (This is the pain with NSB)

Yes. Using the admin tool you can see bindings between exchanges and queues.

7- Does it support complex scenarios where there might be N number of Listeners for a message or a single listener that needs to listen to multiple messages etc?

Yes.

8- Is it configurable from code? (Personally I don’t like to use heave Config files, just personal choice )

Yes.

9- Is the .Net API of RabbitMQ clean or does it make the code messy?

Yes.

Comment: Excellent and to the point answer, just what I had wished for, thanks Jonnii! wish I could give you 20 votes :)